# Is jboss 4.2.2 GA compatible with java 11?

Tags: migration, upgrade, java-11, jboss-4.2.x

We have a product that is running fine with `JBoss 4.2.2/java 7`.
We are now moving to JDK 11. simply added java 11 in the classpath and tried starting the server.

### Encountered below error

> **OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0**
>
> **-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\PathBuilder\GE\EMEA\vp\jboss\lib\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form
> will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.**

removed below configurations from run.bat and started the server again

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
"-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS%"
```

now getting below error and which is

> interrupting the **ear deployment** Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for:
> org.omg.CORBA.Object

Is `Java 4.2.2` compatible with `JDK 11` or we need to update `JBoss` to 7.2 or latest versions?
can someone help with this or provide related links?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the jdk files of older versions like jdk6 and then replace JAVA path in the jboss run file from "set JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" to
"set JAVA=C:\Users\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java"

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 4.2 is a very old and outdated version and it only tested with JDK 1.5 and 1.6 version. If you are upgrading your JDK to 11 then you should update the JBoss to 7.3 version which is the latest available GA release from Red Hat.

Comment: Thanks @Pravin. i will check on that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's better to upgrade to a higher JBoss version... But in case that's not possible, you can avoid the ClassNotFoundException for org.omg.CORBA.Object by placing rt.jar from Java 8 in your JBoss-libs folder.

With this configuration you can run older JBoss versions with Java 11.